# NameError: uninitialized constant RequiredFields when doing a join_table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, join

I am trying to do a join table. My first table is called web_forms with column account_id. Second table is called required_fields with column web_form_id.

I am currently getting the error...

RequiredFields.find(226)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find RequiredField with id=226

```
class WebForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many      :required_fields,
                class_name: RequiredField,
                foreign_key: :web_form_id
end


class RequiredField < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :web_forms,
                           class_name: WebForm,
                           foreign_key: :web_form_id,
                           association_foreign_key: :account_id
end
```

I read through this and it confused me more.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: are you sure you have a record with `id` equal to `226`, rails is telling you that it does not exist.

Comment: in web_forms the account_id is 226 but in required_fields its web_form_id 226.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: so you are trying to look up required_fields by foreign key? looks like you query required_field using its id, which is automatically assigned each time you create a record.

Comment: Ah I see how would I go about searching it by web_form_id instead of just id?

Comment: can you show me the code you are using right now to search

Comment: you can try using the association eg: `form = WebForm.find(226); form.required_fields` will give you all the required fields for any given web-form (split on the `;`, that's just there because code formatting in comments is awful).

Comment: Alternatively, to just use it from RequiredField you'd do: `RequiredField.where(:web_form_id => 226)`

Comment: form = WebForm.find(226);form.required_fields  tried this I am getting undefined method `required_fields' for #<WebForm:0x007fb94c1f9f98>